# Pandas: joining items with same index

Tags: python, pandas, matrix, dataframe

I have a pandas data frame that is a vector with a value and an index, say:

```
row1  10
row1  11
row2  9
row2  8
```

However, I want to create a 2x2 matrix from this, in which the row index is actually a header (column index). Like this:

```
row1  row2
10    9
11    8
```

What is the most efficient way of doing this? This example is a simplification, but I could be dealing with thousands of data points. Does pandas have a specific function for joining items with same index into a table?

Observation: all indexes would have the same number of entries.

Comment: Does the order of 10 and 11 (or 9 and 8) matter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assign another column to the index and unstack

```
s.index = [s.groupby(level=0).cumcount(), s.index]
s.unstack()

0  row1  row2
0    10     9
1    11     8
```

---

***alternative numpy approach***
still slower (blah...)

```
u, inv = np.unique(s.index.values, return_inverse=True)
data = dict(zip(u, [s.values[g] for g in (np.arange(len(u))[:, None] == inv)]))
pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Comment: You got it! Thank you, sir!

Answer (score 2):

You can create an id variable for each unique index and then pivot the table to wide format:

```
df.assign(id = df.groupby([0]).cumcount()).set_index(['id', 0]).unstack(level=1)

#      1
#0  row1    row2
#id     
# 0   10       9
# 1   11       8
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `groupby` on the index to get a list of elements for each index, use `to_dict` to get a dictionary, then use the `pd.DataFrame` constructor:

```
pd.DataFrame(df.groupby(level=0)['column_name'].apply(list).to_dict())
```

If you have a Series, say `s`, instead of a DataFrame you don't need to supply a column name:

```
pd.DataFrame(s.groupby(level=0).apply(list).to_dict())
```

The resulting output:

```
   row1  row2
0    10     9
1    11     8
```

**Timings**

Using the following setup to produce larger sample data, assuming the input data is a DataFrame:

```
n = 10**6
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random(size=n), index=['row1', 'row2']*(n//2))

def pir2(s):
    s.index = [s.groupby(level=0).cumcount(), s.index]
    return s.unstack()
```

I get the following timings:

```
%timeit pd.DataFrame(df.groupby(level=0)[0].apply(list).to_dict())
1 loop, best of 3: 210 ms per loop

%timeit pir2(df.copy())
1 loop, best of 3: 486 ms per loop

%timeit df.assign(id = df.groupby([0]).cumcount()).set_index(['id', 0]).unstack(level=1)
1 loop, best of 3: 1.34 s per loop
```

Comment: @piRSquared -- complexity-wise, do you recommend this answer? And root, indeed, great job.

Comment: @GuilhermeNazarethdeSouza it's a matter of taste.  If you understand what root did (which I don't think is complicated), I'd use this answer.  That said, I'm inspired to add another answer to my post.

Answer (score 2):

And just a little bit faster using @root's example :)

```
pd.DataFrame({name:group.values for name, group in df.groupby(level=0)[0]})
```

Timings:

```
%timeit pd.DataFrame({name:group.values for name, group in df.groupby(level=0)[0]})
10 loops, best of 3: 73.6 ms per loop

%timeit pd.DataFrame(df.groupby(level=0)[0].apply(list).to_dict())
1 loop, best of 3: 249 ms per loop
```